# Nuxt 3 NPM issue

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, node-modules, nuxt3

I am unable to run `npm install` or any other npm commands in my terminal.

I cannot run

```
npm install
npm update
npm install -g npm@latest
```

None of them work.

My setup is

- Nuxt3
- npm 9.6.7
- @vue/cli 4.5.13
- node 20.3.1

I always get the error below.

```
npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for vue@^3.4.14 conflicts with direct dependency
```

Here is the full error in logs file.

```
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@9.6.7
2 info using node@v20.3.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/diba_delight/web/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/davidndanu/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 3ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 3ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm install
21 verbose argv "install"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 7ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/davidndanu/.npm/_logs/2024-02-25T15_34_50_658Z-
26 verbose logfile /Users/davidndanu/.npm/_logs/2024-02-25T15_34_50_658Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 timing command:install Completed in 13ms
33 verbose stack Error: Override for vue@^3.4.14 conflicts with direct dependency
33 verbose stack     at Node.assertRootOverrides (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1334:29)
33 verbose stack     at #loadActual (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/load-actual.js:135:24)
33 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 0)
33 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:159:5)
33 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:147:5)
33 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:89:5)
34 verbose cwd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/diba_delight/web
35 verbose Darwin 23.2.0
36 verbose node v20.3.1
37 verbose npm  v9.6.7
38 error code EOVERRIDE
39 error Override for vue@^3.4.14 conflicts with direct dependency
40 verbose exit 1
41 timing npm Completed in 165ms
42 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1708875290814
43 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1708875290816
44 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree 1708875290817
45 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:init 1708875290817
46 verbose code 1
47 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/davidndanu/.npm/_logs/2024-02-25T15_34_50_658Z-debug-0.log
```

I am confused as to what to do.

```
npm install
npm install --force
npm update
npm install -g npm@latest
```

I expected all node modules to reinstall. I am trying to add @nuxt/image module to the project. I have lost track of where everything went wrong.